# Usage of Server.Execute causes incorrect html generation for IE9 only

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer

Problem - 
I have a page with multiple divs with child divs and in one of the child divs, I am calling server.execute.
The html output as seen in IE debugger for IE10, IE11 look good but for IE9 I got the output of server.execute to be divided into two parts which is causing page to render incorrectly.
The page source look to be same.

Details - 
The aspx page layout is something like this - 
....

```
<form id="mainform">
...
...
<div id="main" >
    <div id="child1" >   
    </div>
    <div id="child2" >
       <div id="child22" >
           Server.Execute("abc.aspx", StringWriterObj, True)
           Response.Write(StringWriterObj)
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="child3" >   
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The HTML output as seen from view source looks to be similar which I compared without tool.
But the browser interpreted HTML output as seen in the IE debugger is different in IE9 and IE10.
For IE 10, the debugger shows only one div element with id "main" as in above code. But for IE9, the debugger shows two div elements with same id "main" as below -

Page DOM as seen in debugger for IE10 -

```
<form id="mainform">
...
...
<div id="main" >
    <div id="child1" >   
    </div>
    <div id="child2" >
       <div id="child22" >
           <Element1>
           <Element2>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="child3" >   
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Page DOM as seen in debugger for IE9 -

```
<form id="mainform">
...
...
<div id="main" >
    <div id="child1" >   
    </div>
    <div id="child2" >
       <div id="child22" >
           <Element1>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div id="main" >
    <div id="child2" >
       <div id="child22" >
           <Element2>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="child3" >   
    </div>
</div>
```

---

As can be seen in the above output for IE9 the div id "main" is present within the form tag and outside as well and contains the elements partially from the page called in Server.Execute() and the next elements in the calling page.

I hope the problem is clear.
Any one faced similar issue. Any hints or ideas would be very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem above was solved after I had removed the html form tag in the abc.aspx page called by Server.Execute method above.